# How to check update is done using php

Tags: php, mysql

How to check the used query is update my table or no using php

below is my code

```
$sql_query = "update companies set 
        first_name = '$first_name',
        last_name = '$last_name',
        designation = '$designation',
        company_name = '$company_name',
        street_address = '$street_address',
        city_code = '$city_code',
        telephone_number = '$telephone_number',
        mobile_number = '$mobile_number',
        fax_number = '$fax_number'
        where company_code='1001';";

    if (!mysqli_query($conn_1,$sql_query) )
    {
        $_SESSION['error_details'][0] = 'no';
        $_SESSION['error_details'][1] = 'Sorry, not update!';
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['error_details'][0] = 'yes';
        $_SESSION['error_details'][1] = 'Thank you, update sucessfully!';   
    }
```

How to check this update in 'if condition'

Comment: `if($_SESSION['error_details'][0] == 'yes'){ //update happened } else { // update did not happen}`?

Comment: Doesn't the manual say anything about error handling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [mysqli.affected-rows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) to check the updated query perform any update or not.

```
if(mysqli_affected_rows($con) > 0) {
    //update performed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Returns the number of rows affected by the last **INSERT**, **UPDATE**, **REPLACE** or **DELETE** query.

`mysqli_affected_rows()` will return the number of rows affected by your update.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Answer (score 0):

PHP just will update if the data that you are updating is different from the data in you database, a good practice is using a class or orm, if you prefer plain php, with class or function take care your are doing something like ( taking care error will be displayed on ly on development time )

```
$result = mysql_query($sqlString) or die(mysql_eror()); // then you will be sure there is no errors;

if (mysql_affected_rows ($result) <= 0) {
//do as you need for no changes on your database
} else {
//do as you want on database changed
}
```

However is better using a ORM or create a class to abstract db connection

Answer (score 0):

The **mysqli_affected_rows()** function returns the number of affected rows in the previous SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE, or DELETE query.

For More:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

```
$conn_1 = mysqli_connect("localhost", "DB_USER", "DB_PASSWORD", "DB_NAME");

    $sql_query = "update companies set 
        first_name = '$first_name',
        last_name = '$last_name',
        designation = '$designation',
        company_name = '$company_name',
        street_address = '$street_address',
        city_code = '$city_code',
        telephone_number = '$telephone_number',
        mobile_number = '$mobile_number',
        fax_number = '$fax_number'
        where company_code='1001'";

     mysqli_query($conn_1,$sql_query);

    if (mysqli_affected_rows($conn_1))
    {

        $_SESSION['error_details'][0] = 'yes';
        $_SESSION['error_details'][1] = 'Thank you, update sucessfully!';
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['error_details'][0] = 'no';
        $_SESSION['error_details'][1] = 'Sorry, not update!';   
    }
```